# How can I create a replica set on MongoDB 4.0

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb4.0

How do I run replica set on MongoDB version 4.0. I am able to do it on the lower versions but I get an error asking me to downgrade my version and protocol version.
Replication is not working on 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You have to migrate your replica set to 4.0 [Upgrade a Replica set to 4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-replica-set/) to use it with Mongo 4.0

Here is the whole doc about replica set : [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: did some adjustments. Can help him/her more because he/her did not provide any code or details